# How to set the new element to a specific column in TableLayout dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamically-generated, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I want to add new ImageViews to tableLayout dynamically. While adding them dynamically, I want to place them whichever column I want. I used "android:layout_weight="7"" in order to divide the row into 8 equal columns. For example I want to add the new Image to the 5th column. The code at below puts the Image always to the first column. How can I do such a thing? What's wrong with the code ? Thanks in advance..

MyActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_table);

    myTable=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);
    tableRow1=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);

    iv_row1_column1=new ImageView(this);

    iv_row1_column1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eight);
    tableRow1.addView(iv_row1_column1, 5);
}
```

XML file:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="7" >
</TableRow>
```

Comment: if u want to play with the alignment u should rather use RelativeLayout instead of TableLayout

Comment: I want to divide the screen into some parts and put images into some parts randomly. Each time screen comes up images will be in the different parts of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GridView to accomplish this.
In the adapter of GridView you can set the visibility to GONE (convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE)) for items which need not be displayed.

for example:-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyContext);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

                ImageView iv= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            }

            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyContext.getResources(), getIconId(position)));
            if(getIconId(position) == R.drawable.blank) {
                convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```